# Login with facebook: where to get access token

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have 'app-id' and 'app-secret' but I am unable to find it that where can I get access token.
Here is code I'am using:

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '{app-id}',
  'app_secret' => '{app-secret}',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.10',
  ]);

try {
  // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
  $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name', '{access-token}');
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

$user = $response->getGraphUser();

echo 'Name: ' . $user['name'];
// OR
// echo 'Name: ' . $user->getName();
```

[official documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_retrieve_user_profile/)

Same question is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45092726/login-with-facebook-grab-access-token) but no answer there, only link of documentation is there and in that documentation there is no mention that where to get access-token.

PS: I am trying to get user information using php.

**Edit:** I've also tried to achieve it without access-token like this `$response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name');` but no luck yet.

Comment: did you tried `echo "<pre/>";print_r($user);` and check that access token is there in the array or not?

Comment: echo "<pre/>";print_r($user) is not showing anything @AlivetoDie

Comment: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: you need to implement login: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_facebook_login - and you need a USER token to access /me

Answer (score 0):

Please go to your app and follow below steps.

```
Open https://developers.facebook.com and click on "tools" then click on "Graph API".

For more information please refer below link
```

https://www.slickremix.com/facebook-60-day-user-access-token-generator/

Comment: Tried it. didn't worked. I think client-token and access-token is not same.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="JavaScript:void(0);" onClick="FacebookLogin(); return false;">
    <img src="images/fb-login.png" class="img-responsive"/>
    <span>Facebook</span>
</a>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: '',
            cookie: true,
            xfbml: true,
            version: 'v2.7'
        });
    };
    (function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    function FacebookLogin() {
        FB.login(function (response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
                FB.api('/me?scope=email&fields=last_name,first_name,email,gender', function (response) {
                    console.debug(response);
                });
            } else {
                console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
            }
        });
     }
</script>
```